# How can I receive an uploaded file using a Golang net/http server?

Tags: go, multipartform-data, httpserver

I'm playing around with [Mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) and `net/http`. Lately, I'm trying to get a simple server with one endpoint to accept a file upload.

Here's the code I've got so far:

**server.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.
        Path("/upload").
        Methods("POST").
        HandlerFunc(UploadCsv)
    fmt.Println("Starting")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

**endpoint.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func UploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseMultipartForm(5 * 1024 * 1024)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(r.FormValue("fileupload"))
}
```

I think I've narrowed the issue down to actually retrieving the body from the request inside `UploadFile`. When I run this cURL command:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/upload -F "fileupload=@test.txt" -vvv
```

I get an empty response (as expected; I'm not printing to the `ResponseWriter`), but I just get a new (empty) line printed at the prompt where I'm running the server, instead of the request body.

I'm sending the file as multipart (AFAIK, implied by using `-F` rather than `-d` in cURL), and cURL's verbose output is showing 502 bytes sent:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/upload -F "fileupload=@test.txt" -vvv
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /upload HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 520
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------b578878d86779dc5
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2016 19:01:50 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

What's the proper way to receive files uploaded as multipart form data using a `net/http` server in Go?

Comment: maybe you are looking for https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile ?

Comment: Also this is what I have used to parse multiple files: https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Form

Comment: @mh-cbon that's it! I get a `[]byte`, which prints properly, which means I've got something to work with. Thanks!

Comment: I have an example here https://github.com/yanpozka/go-httprouter-upfiles-token/blob/master/handlers.go#L49

Comment: @mh-cbon please add your answer as an answer so it can be marked as accepted and this question can be filtered out when people are looking for questions to answer.

Comment: can this be done with a file and a struct in the same request?

Answer (score 51):

Here's a quick example

```
func ReceiveFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20) // limit your max input length!
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    // in your case file would be fileupload
    file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    name := strings.Split(header.Filename, ".")
    fmt.Printf("File name %s\n", name[0])
    // Copy the file data to my buffer
    io.Copy(&buf, file)
    // do something with the contents...
    // I normally have a struct defined and unmarshal into a struct, but this will
    // work as an example
    contents := buf.String()
    fmt.Println(contents)
    // I reset the buffer in case I want to use it again
    // reduces memory allocations in more intense projects
    buf.Reset()
    // do something else
    // etc write header
    return
}
```

Comment: Note that to avoid memory consumption you might write ondisk directly at `io.Copy(&Buf, file)` where Buf is to replace with a File handler.

Comment: True that, large file no es bueno.

Comment: i also put +1 on below answer from keith wachira for pointing it out.

Comment: I checked the error that's return on `defer file.Close()` and it seems the file is unable to be closed -- is that actually needed here?

Comment: Sorry I'm unfamiliar with bitwise operators, but does `32 << 20` have a special meaning?  Is there a reason you use it in this example?

Comment: @ban_javascript in this use case it's shorthand to expand and convert 32 into 32MB as the method takes a read limit in bytes.

see this article demonstrating it further.

https://medium.com/@owlwalks/dont-parse-everything-from-client-multipart-post-golang-9280d23cd4ad

Answer (score 21):

You should use `FormFile` instead of `FormValue`:

```
file, fileHeader, err := r.FormFile("fileupload")
defer file.Close()

// copy example
f, err := os.OpenFile("./downloaded", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
defer f.Close()
io.Copy(f, file)
```

Comment: what if revieving a serialized abject and a file in the same request?

Comment: @pltvs if i pass the content-length explicitly through file upload in postman. handler is throwing an error.  with the above code. looking for suggestions.

Comment: do you mean header instead of handler?

Comment: `"./test/"+handler.Filename` – in general it's a very bad idea to write to files with paths controllable by external input. Don't do this.

Comment: How about uploading multiple files at single upload?

Answer (score 11):

Here a function i wrote to help me in uploading my files.You can check the full version here . [How to upload files in golang](https://kenyaappexperts.com/blog/how-to-upload-files-in-go-step-by-step/)

```golang
package helpers

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

// This function returns the filename(to save in database) of the saved file
// or an error if it occurs
func FileUpload(r *http.Request) (string, error) {
    // ParseMultipartForm parses a request body as multipart/form-data
    r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)

    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file") // Retrieve the file from form data

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer file.Close()                       // Close the file when we finish

    // This is path which we want to store the file
    f, err := os.OpenFile("/pathToStoreFile/"+handler.Filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Copy the file to the destination path
    io.Copy(f, file)

    return handler.Filename, nil
}
```

Comment: The indentation for your attached code is inconsistent, please fix it.

Comment: How about uploading multiple files at single upload?