# Is it possible to upload multiple files at one shoot

Tags: go

I read [this](https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-file-upload-tutorial/) blog and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684307/how-can-i-receive-an-uploaded-file-using-a-golang-net-http-server) question and its answer, but found they are talking about single file only

```golang
    // Parse our multipart form, 10 << 20 specifies a maximum
    // upload of 10 MB files.
    r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)
    // FormFile returns the first file for the given key `myFile`
    // it also returns the FileHeader so we can get the Filename,
    // the Header and the size of the file
    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("myFile")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Retrieving the File")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
```

How can I upload multiple files at one shoot?

If I have the below JavaScript code that upload multiple files, how can I read handle it in Go server

```js
const formData = new FormData();
const photos = document.querySelector('input[type="file"][multiple]');

formData.append('title', 'My Vegas Vacation');
for (let i = 0; i < photos.files.length; i++) {
  formData.append('photos', photos.files[i]);
}

fetch('https://example.com/posts', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
  console.log('Success:', result);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

With HTML element:

```html
<input type="file" multiple />
```

Or with:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
/*more specific selector: 
  "input[type=file][name=file1],input[type=file][name=file2],input[type=file][name=file3]"*/
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file]").forEach(
    input=>formData.append('photos',input.files[0]);
```

If HTML elements are separate like:

```html
<input name="file1" type="file" />
<input name="file2" type="file" /> 
<input name="file3" type="file" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Request.FormFile](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.FormFile) is helper method for accessing a single file in [Request.MultipartForm](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.MultipartForm).  Use [Request.MultipartForm](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.MultipartForm) directly to access multiple files for a key:

```
err := r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)
if err != nil {
     // handle error
}
for _, fh := range r.MultipartForm.File["photos"] {
    f, err := fh.Open()
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error
    }
    // Read data from f
    f.Close()
}
```

If the input elements have unique keys as in the last snippet of HTML, then call `r.FormFile(key)` for each unique key.